# Ошибка в акронисе

Tags: usb, persistence, live-usb, kali-linux

Здравствуйте. Подскажите почему когда я пытаюсь в Acronis'е "разделить" флешку (для того чтобы можно было сделать kali linux PERSISTENCE), то при перезапуске, когда по идее изменения должны вступить в силу, вылазит косяк...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое сообщение гласит:
Команда ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТ ОТСУТСТВУЮЩИЙ ОБЪЕКТ
Второе:
КОМА­ДА СОДЕРЖИТ НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР

Расшифровать этот текст можно на https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/, введя закорючки, которые являются исковерканным русским текстом.

И хотя этот совет наверное не будет корректным в рамках правил, но основываясь на многолетнем опыте использования продуктов Акронис скажу: НИКОГДА не пользуйтесь ими, если не хотите проблем в будущем. В данном случае программа сломалась, ей чего-то нехватает, но она даже не может корректно об этом сообщить пользователю. Подобные вещи отлично говорят о качестве продуктов этой компании.

Разметить флешку можно кучей утилит, которые наверняка уже есть в вашем дистрибутиве, такими как cfdisk / gparted.

Comment: Кароче убогая прога как я понял, хорошо, спасибо )